# What type of analysis: repeated measures, one way Anova or a paired t test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

For a design study, I have protocols from 5 different design groups with two persons in each team. The verbal utterance of each group (two persons) are transcribed for each sentence. The data are derived from each line of transcription for the analysis. I want to analyze two cases:

1. I want to compare the differences between two persons in different groups.
2. I want to compare different groups functions.

Which types of analysis should I take for the two above?

Answer (score 0):

The "two persons" in each group are different, thus your experiment shouldn't be "repeated" or "paired". Your experiment is the classical [Completely Randomized Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_randomized_design). Assume you have checked the usual ANOVA assumptions, you may want to use one-factor ANOVA.

Note you've barely reached the minimum sample size for ANOVA. You'll suffer low-power and sensitivity to the normal assumption. I would've done a better experiment.

> [Minimum sample size for 1 way ANOVA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129755/minimum-sample-size-for-1-way-anova)