# Can you run a two-way ANOVA if your n=7 but with assumptions met?

Tags: anova

I recall from my stats course that there is a certain n where if it is too small you should just do a non-parametric test regardless but I can't recall what that number was.

Comment: Related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129755/minimum-sample-size-for-1-way-anova

Comment: Context would be helpful: what are you trying to achieve? Is this for a homework assignment? A real problem?

Comment: It is characteristic of almost all non-parametric tests that when $n$ is sufficiently small they have no power and are useless.  This suggests your recollection might be the opposite of what was taught in the stats course.  Regardless, this threshold for $n$ must depend on the test: there is no universal answer.  For ANOVA, that means the number of degrees of freedom will be relevant as well as the expected cell means.